# OLEDB is not able to read only one column from excel

Tags: c#

I have one excel sheet which is having total 72 columns and am trying to read all data from excel sheet with oledb connection. OLEDB connection is able to read 71 columns from Excel sheet but 1 column (Sub-Brand) it's not able to read.

Could any one help me to check what is the issue with code or excel sheet?
Below is the code which, am using to read excel.

```
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\test 1706_JVNOA.PAYROLL.XLSB';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [YFU7$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("YFU7", "TestTable");
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();
```

Please find the Excel sheet from below URL, which is having problem.

Comment: where is the URL to download excel?

Comment: You can try changing the IMEX=2 to IMEX=1 in your OleDBConnection.

Comment: I have tried with IMEX=1 but still not able to get that 1 column.

Comment: This is the Excel sheet download link : 
  
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_0dk_rnbL0YbTFMeUJNVExmUHM/view?usp=sharing